# How to use json in Android with Retrofit

Tags: android

In my application I want get some data from server and show this into list (`recyclerview`)! 
I receive data from server such as below :

```
 "data": {
      "id": 1812286134,
      "Cr": "85",
      "BUN": "87",
      "ALP": "75",
      "ALT": "6",
      "AST": "6",
      "Chol": "55",
      "HDL": "545",
      "LDL": "45",
      "TG": "4",
      "created_at": "2022-10-30 16:05:50",
      "updated_at": "2022-10-30 16:05:50"
    }
```

**UPDATE** : 
This data may update in some time, added new items or remove items by admins

I should show all of this items into `recyclerview`. 
I know in above **json** data should **list** but has **object**. 
But backend developer tells me convert all of this data to list with key value! 
My question is can I convert this data to list and use all of items into list ? 
How can I it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Map<String,String>` in your Response or whatever you used.

It will be something like this.

```
@GET
fun getCurrency():Response<DataResponse>

data class DataResponse(
val currencies:Map<String,String>
)
```